# C++ - "My_Array" is not declared in this scope - Easy Program

Tags: c++, arrays, scope

so I'm writing a very basic code, it's supposed to go through an array (Despite how inefficiently I'm implementing this) and see if any two elements int he array are equal to a third predefined sum. I keep getting a "not declared in this scope) issue, however, and I have no Idea why as this is all in the same function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
int n=0, sum = 0, key = 1, counter = 0; 

cout << "Please enter the number of variables you wish to compare:" <<" ";
cin >> n ;
if (n < 2)
{
    do
        {
            cout<<"Error! -- you must enter 2 or more variables to     continue!"<< endl<< "Please enter the number of variables you wish to compare:" <<" ";
            cin >> n;
        } while (n <2);
}
else
{
    int My_Array[n];
    cout << "Please Enter "<< n <<" numbers" <<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> My_Array[i];
        cout << "You've entered"<<" "<<i+1<<" numbers"<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
cout << "Please enter the number to which you believe the addens are present in the previously entered number(s):"<<" ";
cin >> sum;

for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {

      key = sum - My_Array[i];
      for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(key - My_Array[j] == 0)
                {
                    counter++;
                 }
        }
    }
cout <<"There are "<< counter << " numbers that equal "<< sum<<" in this array";
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the whole error.

Comment: You've declared `My_Array` inside an `else` block, it cannot be seen outside the block (and is destroyed at the end of the block anyway).

Comment: @user657267: You beat me to it. Post it as an answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Beta I'm not really that bothered, this question probably has a dupe somewhere anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You declared `My_Array` inside an `else` block. Once control passes out of that block, as far as the stack is concerned it no longer exists and you may not refer to it.

Comment: Yup. It's a scoping issue. You might consider reading: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/ and focus on the section about block scope.